# How to redirect to a external page?

Tags: next.js

So, I need to redirect to a external page when my site return 400. I've tried follow the Next.js redirect tutorial, didn't work, and I've tried with window.locate, but breaks my site in production.
Here's the code I've tried:

```
import React from 'react'
import Router from 'next/router'

export default class extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ res }) {
    if (res) {
      res.writeHead(302, {
        Location: 'http://google.com'
      })
      res.end()
    } else {
      Router.push('/')
    }
    return {}
  }
}
```

Is there another solution without the window.locate method?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

indeed that is the bad side from next.js the routing is not working well.
i get the same issue before than i change it back to reactjs

kind regards

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, this kind a problem has a lot of a requests in their github, but they never solve it... Oh well...